# Reason(s) why $f(z)=1/(z-z_0)$ is not analytic at $z=z_0$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, continuity, analytic-functions

I am studying complex analysis and I am confused about why $f(z)=1/(z-z_0)$ is not analytic at $z=z_0$. For a function to be analytic, it must be differentiable and single-valued. Obviously, $f'(z)=-1/(z-z_0)^2$ is not defined at $z=z_0$, so the derivative does not exist. Also, $f(z)=1/(z-z_0)$ is not defined at $z=z_0$, so $f$ is not single-valued at $z=z_0$. (?)

Am I right? So, my question is actually whether both non-differentiability and not being a single-valued function both apply to this case. I know that either is enough to show non-analyticity.

Comment: The point isn't even in the domain of the function so it's not possibly analytic there. As for why it cannot be extended to be analytic there, it is because it is a pole and not a removal singularity (meaning it is not bounded in a neighborhood of the point).

Comment: Got it! Is $f(z)$ single-valued on a region $R$ containing $z_0$ ? If it is, then the only reason why $f(z)$ is not analytic on $R$ is that the derivative is not defined/ does not exist on $z_0$ because the function isn't even defined there, correct?

Comment: Well $f$ isn't even truly defined on a region containing $z_0$, so it's hard to address that part, but yes the other parts are fine.

Comment: I think you have some misunderstanding about functions in general. Functions have a domain. Continuous/differentiable/analytic/etc. are properties functions can have in points of their domain. It just makes no sense to even ask wether a function is analytic in a point that's not in its domain. Such a point effectively doesn't exist, as far as the function is concerned. Instead of asking wether the function is analytic in $z_0$, you could just as well ask wether its analytic in Paris. The function doesn't know what Paris is, and it doesn't know what $z_0$ is, since neither is in its domain.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Correct, but a tad pedantic; when someone talks about being analytic at $z_0$, they are essentially always talking about the existence of an analytic continuation in a neighborhood of $z_0$. While I agree the distinction should be made clear to beginners, the abuse of notation is so prevalent that I would not completely cast it aside.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: in my experience, mostly beginners use that wording, while more experienced people will use the more precise formulation of analytic continuation, or in the case of complex analysis they'll talk about removable singularities or meromorphicity (implying that we're actually talking about analyticity as a function to the Riemann sphere). Do you often hear people who know the distinction make the abuse of notation? (This is not a rhetorical question, I'm willing to take your personal experience into account).